# How do I award a bounty after it was auto-awarded?

Tags: support, bounty

I put a bounty on one of my questions over a week ago but had some major life events and wasn't able to get back in time to award it! Half the bounty was auto-awarded to the highest rated answer, but I've accepted another answer.

I would like to award a (second) bounty to this person as well to thank them for their contribution, but the button seems to have disappeared (probably due to my earlier negligence). Any way I can make this happen? I'm aware that my other 50% can't be rewarded/refunded which is okay as it's my bad!

The thread in question is [here](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/72052/how-do-i-use-weird-bouncing-magic-to-power-my-society). The auto-awarded person had an awesome answer, but the other answerer did such a great job with both design and clarification questions that I think he deserves kudos.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Welcome to the club.  Additional bounties have to be higher! You can’t just give 50 to each, I’ve found.

Comment: Dear Dog: don't stress it. I've got plenty of yummy atta-boy points for my casual indiscretion as a low rent engineer. I'm not particularly creative where it counts - I troubleshoot, manipulate and revise; the thing I posted is merely a logical consequence of your creative vision. Keep up the good work.

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately, once a bounty has been awarded or has expired without being awarded, there's nothing we can do to change it.  You can start a second bounty and manually award it, but I'm afraid the original one is gone.

According to the [bounty documentation on Meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work) (why is this not linked from the Help Center? hmm), you have to double the bounty amount for an additional bounty:

> Note that if you offer several bounties on the same question, you will have to double the amount each time (or more). That is, if your first bounty was worth 50 reputation, your second bounty on the same question will have to be for at least 100, your third for at least 200 and so on. If you've already offered a bounty for more than 250, you can still offer more bounties for 500 (the maximum amount) as long as you like (or as long as you have the rep). This doubling applies only to bounties by the same user on the same question.

My guess is that you don't see the "start bounty" link because your first bounty was for 100 rep and you don't have 200 rep available right now for a new bounty.  If you keep asking and answering questions on main, you'll probably get it before too long.  Alternatively, perhaps somebody else seeing this discussion will be motivated to start a bounty.

Now that you've linked to the question on meta, the answer you accepted will probably get some more attention from the community, possibly including upvotes.  Maybe that's some consolation?

Comment: That's my problem--how do I start the second bounty?

Comment: @Dog oh I see now.  See my update.